# opConfig is undefined Magento Detail Page and Custom Option

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.9.2 When We change Custom Option Price Not Change and JavaScript error TypeError: opConfig is undefined

https://www.muscularindia.com/ud/index.php/protien/whey-protien/dymatize-elite-xt.html

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling jQuery's "$.noConflict" method too late on your page, so it is conflicting with prototype thus breaking your options. If you move the call to right after you load jQuery, it should resolve your problem. The easiest way you can do this is by simply adding the call to the bottom of your jQuery file, or you can add it to its own file and include it in the xml right after jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

go to app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme/layout/catalog.xml

in below action

```
<catalog_product_view>
</catalog_product_view>
```

add this code

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

</reference>
```